# NGINX: Serve static files from different locations

Tags: django, apache, file, nginx, static

I have 2 servers implemented on two different machines (different IP adresses). Lets call them **serverA** and **serverB**.

**serverA** is where **serverB** is going to feed for some static files.

**serverA** configuration file is:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=lmz_serverA:10m rate=5r/s;

server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    server_name serverA;

    location /server_a {
    limit_req zone=lmz_serverA burst=5 nodelay;
    rewrite /server_a/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_intercept_errors     on;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    location /static/BIG/ {
    root /safe/server_a/;
    autoindex off;
    expires 7d;
    }

    location /server_a/static/{
    root /safe/;
    autoindex off;
    expires 7d;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico{
    alias /safe/server_a/static/images/favicon.ico;
    }
}
```

**serverB** configuration file is:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=lmz_serverB:10m rate=5r/s;

server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    server_name serverB;

    location /server_b {
    limit_req zone=lmz_serverB burst=5 nodelay;
    rewrite /server_b/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_intercept_errors     on;
    proxy_pass http://1.0.0.0:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /server_b/static/ {
    root /safe/;
    autoindex off;
    expires 7d;
    }
```

--- end

Now, imagine that this servers are in different continents.. some static files are **OK** to be served from **serverA** but the BIG (/static/BIG/) stuff is giving me some trouble because the majority of users are in the same continent of **serverB**. So I want to cut those  BIG static files from **serverA** and put them on **serverB** so they can be more easily downloaded.

Does anyone have any idea how can I accomplish that just by making those files available on **serverB** and changing nginx configuration files?

**IMPORTANT**: **serverA** implements a Django application named **appA**, and **serverB** implements a different (yet still Django) application named **appB**. I can't change the code of those two apps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled onto this while searching for something similar -- **how to serve a *different filename* than what's requested**.  My final solution:

```
location /robots.txt {
       # Try the beta file, which has a disallow everything
       root /location/to/static/files;
       try_files /robots-beta.txt =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `302 Moved Temporarily` redirect from the server which wants another one to serve the big files.

```
server_name serverA;
location /static/BIG/ {
    return  302 $scheme://serverB$uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try! Does serverB serve directly the files to the requester, or the files will travel from serverB to serverA and then served (making serverA working a proxy)? I wanted the files to serve directly, because in the other case I would not gain anything.

Comment: They would be served directly.  But notice that a request would still be made to serverA (accompanied by a very tiny redirect response), so, latency would suffer -- if that's not what you want, then you should just change the html to reference /static/BIG/ directly on serverB.

Comment: Sorry for being lame, but.. at line "return  302 $scheme://serverB$uri;"
if serverB had the ip: 1.1.1.1 and the folder and the location would be the same /static/BIG how would you rewrite the line?

return 302 $scheme:http://1.1.1.1/static/BIG   ???

Comment: ok, it was exactly like you said.. return  302 scheme://1.1.1.1$uri;
all the static gets served but some flash stuff.. I get:
crossdomain.xml GET 404 Not Found